# How to send emails with an Arduino without using a computer?

Tags: arduino, communication, microcontroller, ethernet

I'm experimenting with my [Arduino Mega](http://arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardMega). I also have an [Arduino Ethernet Shield](http://arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoEthernetShield).

I need to send emails using them, **without the help of a computer** (or any other device; like a smartphone, etc.). Though I could find several articles, I couldn't find any acceptable solution...

How can I do it? As I'm not asking this to be used for any special application, you can 
make any assumption about missing details.

Comment: you need a tcp/ip stack, and then the mail protocol is fairly simple, see the rfc for SMTP, for the protocol.  the tcp/ip stack is the hard part unless there is already a/some canned solution(s)

Comment: An Arduino would probably be a poor choice for sending or receiving emails.  If you're in a DIY frame of mind, take a byte out of [Raspberry PI](http://www.raspberrypi.org/) :).

Comment: +1 @paulsm4 for your suggestion, but at the moment I've do it through the Arduino.. Hope someone'll show me a way..

Comment: Thanks @dwelch but I lack enough time to experiment with that (of course I'll try in my free time). Guess there'll be someone experienced.. Prefer a complete _(roughly)_ example..

Comment: @Anubis - please describe the "use case" for this e-mail.  Who or what initiates it?  Some "event", or a user?  What will the message contain?  Who will be receiving it?  How exactly will your Arduino board interface to something that's connected to the Internet?  Are you sure there can't be any devices like a PC, a smart phone or even a Linksys router (which you can "hack" into a nifty web server/web relay) between the Arduino (which is good at generating/receiving signals) and the Internet?

Comment: @paulsm4 as I mentioned, I'm experimenting with my Arduino mega. There's no any special purpose, event etc... So, you can assume the simplest thing. Something like sending an email containing some text _("Wow..It Works!!")_ to my email address when i press a button which is connected to the Arduino. Or anything simpler.. then i'll be able to dig further for more advanced applications later...

Comment: This will be one of my favorite questions. You may find this post (http://www.arduino.cc/cgi-bin/yabb2/YaBB.pl?num=1235534880/3) helpful (I'm not saying it'll answer your question). I'm sure the experts @ stackOverflow will give a clear answer (if there is any)..I'm also waiting..thank you @Anubis for the post..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the discussion above in comments it sounds like you either need code from someone who has just done it for you or you need to take the time to learn about the components and find or make the components.

They wouldn't make an Ethernet shield for this platform if it was only useful for non-standard packets. So someone somewhere has created some level of an IP stack.

Backing up though, in order to send mail you need to learn the [Simple Mail Transfer Protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Mail_Transfer_Protocol) (SMTP). Almost all Internet protocol definitions are defined using something called [RFCs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Request_for_Comments) (Request for Comments). So if you google SMTP RFC you will find [RFC 2821](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2821.txt).

[IETF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Engineering_Task_Force) is Internet engineering task force. There will be many copies of these documents on many websites. And due to the age of the Internet and these protocols in many cases you will find that one RFC has been created to replace a prior one. Version numbers are not used, but it is kind of like HTML 1.0 then HTML 2.0 and so on. I recommend even though the RFC says that it completely replaces RFC xyz, go find RFC xyz and read it. I go back as far as I can find learn that one then work my way forward.

Many/most protocols that ride on top of [TCP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol) (TCP is yet another protocol defined in an RFC, more on that later) are ASCII based, makes it very easy to, for example, Telnet to learn/experiment with the protocol, you can probably use Telnet to learn SMTP.

Most protocols are some sort of a half duplex thing, make a connection and often the server sends you a string, you see that string and then you send some sort of hello string, the server responds with some sort of OKAY or fail status. For SMTP, you then do some sort of *I am mailing from this email address*, server says OKAY, you say I want to mail this person or this list of people, for each email address you get an okay or fail. Eventually, you tell the server you are ready to send the body of the message, you do that, end the message with the defined termination. Then either the server says okay or fail or maybe there is some more handshaking.

The protocols in general though have this back and forth. Usually you are sending strings with commands and usually the server side sends back a short okay or error. Sometimes, if they want, they send back more detail on the error, but always start with the few bytes that indicate okay or error. The protocols generally have a flow, you must do this first then this then that.

You should learn sockets programming, sometimes called [Berkeley sockets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berkeley_sockets). You can write programs that are mostly portable across unixes but also across to Windows using Windows sockets if that is your platform of choice. You need to learn the protocol first, and it is better on your desktop/laptop and not embedded, you can get it done faster there. You do NOT have to learn to fork or thread to use sockets. The examples may show that as it is easy to show it that way, but you can write complete applications using polling only, it is half duplex send something, wait, send something, wait. For these simple learning programs, a little time up front to learn sockets, from there, it is all learning the protocols.

Now that was the very easy part, the hard part is the TCP/IP stack. I do not recommend attempting that without gaining a lot more experience taking baby steps on your way there.  For example, learn to respond to [ARP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_Resolution_Protocol) first (yet another RFC protocol, address resolution protocol) then [ping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ping_%28networking_utility%29) ([ICMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Control_Message_Protocol) echo, one subset of the ICMP protocols) then [IP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Protocol) basics (sniffing packets) then receive and generate [UDP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Datagram_Protocol) packets. TCP is a whole other level above that, more handshaking. It is not fixed packet size, ***it is streaming, do not have your code operate on packets, it is a stream of bytes***, like working with a serial port.

Doing your own TCP stack is very much a non-trivial thing, I don't recommend it, you need to find someone that has done a TCP/IP stack for this platform for the Ethernet shield and just use it, whatever [RTOS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-time_operating_system) or environment they use, use it. Then take your desktop/laptop based experience with the protocol and apply that.

From the discussion above, if you don't want to learn the protocols, etc., I think you need to google around looking at Arduino Ethernet shield examples and see if anyone has done something that sends emails.

Comment: Appreciate your great answer! Okay, I give up.. I'll try to face this by myself. Actually, I'm experienced in using some of the (simple) protocols you've mentioned. But yes, I don't have that much of knowledge about TCP/IP stack (not saying i know nothing)..Of course, I was looking for an easy solution. But I think I won't get a better answer than this..Many thanks!

Comment: I didnt know what your experience level was.  The packet structures are pretty straight forward, keeping track of things with the back and forth, etc is where it gets more complicated, esp if trying to do it on such a limited platform.  Googling myself though it appears the shield uses a wiznet chip. so the stack is done for you in hardware and the arduino sandbox appears to make things not so painful. http://arduino.cc/en/Guide/ArduinoEthernetShield

Comment: TCP/IP is already built into the Arduino Ethernet shield, in the W5100 chip. E.g. from [Arduino Ethernet Shield](http://arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoEthernetShield): "Ethernet Controller: W5100 with internal 16K buffer ... The Wiznet W5100 provides a network (IP) stack capable of both TCP and UDP". [W5100 datasheet](http://www.wiznet.co.kr/UpLoad_Files/ReferenceFiles/W5100_Datasheet_v1.2.2.pdf).

Comment: right, that is what I said, the stack is done for you in hardware.